# which static assertions should I use before type punning?

Tags: c, type-punning

I made the following set of macros for type punning:

```
#define PUN(type, var)                                                        \
        _Static_assert(sizeof(type) <= sizeof(var), "Bad pun alias");         \
        _Static_assert(_Alignof(type) <= _Alignof(var), "Bad pun alignment"); \
        (*(type *)&(var)) // only use for lvalue punning, otherwise use PUN_SAFE
#define PUN_SAFE(type, var) ({ type _##type;    \
        memset(&(_##type), 0, sizeof(_##type)); \
        memcpy(&_##type, &(var), sizeof(var));  \
        _##type; })
```

I'm getting that itchy "you've missed something" feeling, especially for the PUN macro. Should I be checking something other than size and alignment?

Related: I'm using gcc, which helpfully tells me that PUN sometimes violates strict aliasing. Are the above static assertions enough to justify -Wno-strict-aliasing (assuming all type punning happens via these macros)? Or will optimizations (I use -Os) cause lots of bugs without -fno-strict-aliasing?

I've tested these with [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PhnzTsdsY) with `-Wall -Wextra -Os` and it seems the memset and memcpy in PUN_SAFE are usually (but not always) optimized out?

Comment: You generally should not be using aliasing often enough that you need macros for it. Where it is necessary, it should be confined to a carefully designed portion of the program, and the reasons for it and the steps that have been taken to ensure it works should be documented. Those steps including using GCC’s `-fno-strict-aliasing` switch. And when `-fno-strict-aliasing` is operative, `-Wstrict-aliasing` is inactive, [per GCC’s documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.1.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Comment: Re “Or will optimizations (I use -Os) cause lots of bugs without -fno-strict-aliasing?”: The `-fno-strict-aliasing` switch is designed to allow code that does aliasing to work. When you do not use it, you should not expect the code to work, regardless of any checks you make on the size or the alignment of the types. Even if two incompatible types have the same size and the same alignment requirement, aliasing them without `-fno-strict-aliasing` can break.

Comment: @KamilCuk: The comment says “only use for lvalue punning”. Presumably they intend `PUN(type, x) = y`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I'll use `-fno-strict-aliasing` with these. 

Re "You generally should not be using aliasing often enough that you need macros for it": I often use macros to ensure consistency, rather than because I need to repeat code a bunch. In this case, I want to ensure that any aliasing (regardless of frequency) I do uses macros that will do the appropriate checks.